# How to enumerate all QObject classes in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qobject

Is there a way to enumerate all QObject classes declared in an application or DLL? I am trying to create an application that loads DLLs and lists all QObject classes inside the DLLs.

Update: Actually I am trying to create a Unit Test GUI. It will load DLLs, instantiate the QObject inside, and call QTest::qExec against them.

Comment: You can try messing around with the moc

Comment: Are you wanting to enumerate all QObject's subclasses used in the DLL or all instances?

Comment: @AndréPuel All QObject subclasses only, not their instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the program code is not stripped you can get some instrospection by reading the binary:
`objdump -demangle=C++ -t SomeQtLibrary.so |grep qt_static_metacall` it shows roughly the QObject derived classes. I think they all implement this symbol. Of couse since you are on Windows you would have to use Windows tools such as `nm` (correct me if I am wrong). Naturally processing the symbols in-code is also possible, but this is a separate topic.

The command I mentioned returns this for example:

```
0000000000470c00 l     F .text  0000000000000014              QxtBoundFunction::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)
00000000004392ea l     F .text  0000000000000158              MainWindow::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)
0000000000453b5c l     F .text  0000000000000091              QtLocalPeer::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)
0000000000438508 l     F .text  0000000000000014              MyApplication::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)
0000000000442cd0 l     F .text  0000000000000080              MessagePoll::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)
0000000000442ea2 l     F .text  0000000000000091              RFBClient::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)
0000000000467c3c l     F .text  000000000000436a              QxtRPCService::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)
0000000000439114 l     F .text  000000000000008f              MemoryPolling::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)
```

If you are interested in run-time introspection than you would have to play with the [QMetaObject](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qmetaobject.html#superClass) class on each object.

For objects that were registered as [QMetaType](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qmetatype.html) (and only those!) you can do some additional magic to bring them to life. Not very easy, and not out of the box - but it is still hell of a lot from such a static language. Here is a snippet from Qt docs (changed `if(id == 0)` to `if(id)`).

```
 int id = QMetaType::type("MyClass");
 if (id) {
     void *myClassPtr = QMetaType::construct(id);
     ...
     QMetaType::destroy(id, myClassPtr);
     myClassPtr = 0;
 }
```

Comment: Nice catch. However, you can't always tell from the class name what other classes it inherits, right? So, for instance, if I will throw in my class inherited from QObject, which doesn't have any slots, you will never be able to tell it.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I instantiate the classes found using this way? Sorry about not mentioning instantiation in the initial question.

Comment: Updated, but it is definitely over the top.

Comment: Thanks again, shouldn't it be "if (id) {"? Anyway, QMetaType::type should have the registered class list. I will trace it. That should solve the problem. Sorry can't upvote due to my low reputation :)